# Register class in String Template Resource

Tags: smarty

In Smarty, when I use `{include file="string:$template_string"}`, any classes registered on the current template through [registerClass()](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.class.tpl) are not available in the new compiled template based on `$template_string`. Is there any way to make the classes registered in the current template also available in the included template? If I use `{include file="eval:$template_string"}` instead, the registered classes are available in the included template, but the performance impact is large, since the compiled template is not stored and the code is in a loop.

Here is an example to clarify the issue using two template files. PHP creates a Smarty template for `display.tpl`, which extends `listing.tpl`. The class `User` is registered to the template, and an array variable `$items` is assigned to the template. The purpose of the templates is to have one generic table template, which can be extended by other templates specifying the the column titles and values.

File: `listing.tpl`

```
{strip}{block name="properties"}{assign var="properties" value=[]}{/block}{/strip}{* extending templates should assign the variable $properties in this block *}
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
{foreach $properties as $property}
         <th>{$property[0]}</th>
{/foreach}
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
{foreach $items as $item}
      <tr>
{foreach $properties as $property}
         <td>{include file="string:{$property[1]}"}</td>{* this is much faster than {include file="eval:{$property[1]}"} *}
{/foreach}
      </tr>
{/foreach}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

File: `display.tpl`

```
{extends file="listing.tpl"}
{block name="properties"}
{assign var="properties" value=
   [ [_("Id"), '{$item->id}']
   , [_("Title"), '{$item->title}']
   , [_("User"), '{User::getName($item, "creator")}']
   ]
}
{/block}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `scope` option?

Comment: Adding `scope` on `assign` or `include` only affect whether newly created variables and changes made to variables are visible in the including template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted all the compiled template files, and now it works! It seems some template file(s) had to be recompiled after registering the new class `User`, and were not recompiled automatically. So that's the lesson: if something is not working in Smarty that you don't see a reason why shouldn't work, try deleting the compiled templates and maybe it will work after a recompilation!